# Android - How to send a double value to the ws service

Tags: android, ksoap

I am trying to send a double value to the web service using ksoap library. 
This is what I tried, but it doesn't work. Can anybody explain how to make this work.

```
public String getDataForStaticSearch() throws SoapFault   
{  

    String data = "";
    String serviceUrl = RB_Constant.RB_Webservice_URL;
    String serviceNamespace = RB_Constant.RB_Webservice_Namespace; 
    String soapAction = "http://www.roadbrake.com/GetSearchResultsV2";
    String type_of_soap = "GetSearchResultsV2";  

    PropertyInfo headingdirectionObj = new PropertyInfo ();
    headingdirectionObj.name = "headingdirection";
    headingdirectionObj.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;  

    try
    {
        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(serviceNamespace, type_of_soap);

        //  strUserLatitude and strUserLongitude are of type double.
        // How to pass these values to ws.  
        Request.addProperty("strUserLatitude", 33.924012);          
        Request.addProperty("strUserLongitude", -118.3832772);

         //headingdirectionObj is of type int
        Request.addProperty(headingdirectionObj, 0);

        System.out.println("Request Value->"+Request.toString());

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        try
        {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(serviceUrl);
            androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Webservice calling error ->"+e.toString());
        }

        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        data = response.toString();
        System.out.println("web service response->"+response.toString());   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Soap Method Error ->"+e.toString());    
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Please Provide some details with what u have done.....

Comment: i updated the post please refer that

Comment: @naresh I too need to send the double values of lat and long to the WSDL servieces and getting an Internal Service Fault Exception. Can you please help me in this ?

Comment: I have used your marshal class, but how to implement it in my values ?

Comment: @nareshCan you help me please

Answer (score 6):

To be exact use it like this

the Marshal class

```
import org.ksoap2.serialization.Marshal;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MarshalDouble implements Marshal {
    public Object readInstance(XmlPullParser parser, String namespace, String name,
                               PropertyInfo expected) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

        return Double.parseDouble(parser.nextText());
    }


    public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope cm) {
        cm.addMapping(cm.xsd, "double", Double.class, this);

    }


    public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer writer, Object obj) throws IOException {
        writer.text(obj.toString());
    }
}

the implementation

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

**MarshalDouble md = new MarshalDouble();
md.register(envelope);**
```

Comment: I wonder whos the idiot who downvoted my post without leaving a message!?

Comment: I did, but it was -1 right? Should I send you a screenshot? :)

Comment: @IamStalker I have used your marshal class, but how to implement it in my values. I want to send Latitude and Longitude as parameters, and unable to get the response from the service, can you please help me

Comment: Can you see the envelope? I've just had to register it and that's it.

Comment: After one week of headache finally found a solution :)

Comment: @mes nice to know that someone found that useful.